# Nested If Statement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on form validation in jQuery.  There are three options for payment (credit, bitcoin, paypal).  When a user selects anything aside from credit card and submits, the form is triggering calls to credit card validation, even though I've added language to stop if selection is not credit card.  It is also resetting the value to credit card.

[here is jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58bkgkhd/)

I do have code which hides or shows fields based on payment selection

```
//Changes Payment Sections Based on User Payment Choice
$('#bitcoin').hide();
$('#paypal').hide();
$("#payment option[value='credit card']").prop('selected', true);
$('#payment').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 'credit card' ){
      $('#bitcoin').hide();
      $('#paypal').hide();
      $('#credit-card').show();
    } else if ( $(this).val()=='paypal' ){
      $('#paypal').show();
      $('#credit-card').hide();
      $('#bitcoin').hide();
    } else if ( $(this).val()=='bitcoin'){
      $('#paypal').hide();
      $('#credit-card').hide();
      $('#bitcoin').show();
    }

});
```

and this is what is happening on form submission

```
// On Form Submission Validate Form
$("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
    error_name = validateName();
    error_email = validateEmail();
    error_activity = validateActivities();
    isCreditIssue = validateCredit();

    var valid = true;

    if ((error_name) || (error_email) || (error_activity) || (isCreditIssue)){
        console.log("errors");
        valid = false;
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert('GREAT! form completed');
        valid = true;
    }
    if (valid) {
    return;
    }


});
```

and here is validateCredit Function.  my hunch is maybe that the nested if I have here might not be working correctly. I've tried to alter this a bit but can't get anything to work correctly.

```
//Check for Credit Card Issue -- Any problems with CC, Zip Code or CVV
function validateCredit(){
    var credit = $("#payment option[value='credit card']");
    var paypal = $("#payment option[value='paypal']");
    var bitcoin = $("#payment option[value='bitcoin']");

    isCreditIssue = false;


    if (credit.prop('selected', true)){
      errorCC = validateCC();
      errorZip = validateZip();
      errorCVV = validateCVV();

      if ((errorCC) || (errorZip) || (errorCVV)){
      isCreditIssue = true;
      console.log('credit issue');
    } }
    else if (bitcoin.prop('selected', true)){
      console.log('bitcoin');
      isCreditIssue = false;

    } else if (paypal.prop('selected', true)){
      console.log('paypal');
      isCreditIssue = false;
    }

    return isCreditIssue;
}
```

Comment: You are setting the property value not getting one. Have a look at the documentation for [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: you are very right...thanks so much

Comment: Just a comment... If you change the value `credit card` to `credit-card` your payment change handler could be reduced to: `$("#bitcoin, #paypal, #credit-card").hide().filter("#" + this.value).show()` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drg74k1v/))

Comment: @Andreas ---ah...very nice.. i like that thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value of the property, not setting it, by giving the function `prop` a second argument:

```
function validateCredit(){
        var credit = $("#payment option[value='credit card']");
        var paypal = $("#payment option[value='paypal']");
        var bitcoin = $("#payment option[value='bitcoin']");

        isCreditIssue = false;


        if (credit.prop('selected'){
          errorCC = validateCC();
          errorZip = validateZip();
          errorCVV = validateCVV();

          if ((errorCC) || (errorZip) || (errorCVV)){
          isCreditIssue = true;
          console.log('credit issue');
        } }
        else if (bitcoin.prop('selected')){
          console.log('bitcoin');
          isCreditIssue = false;

        } else if (paypal.prop('selected'){
          console.log('paypal');
          isCreditIssue = false;
        }

        return isCreditIssue;
    }
```